# Distinguish which authentication mechanism used

Tags: symfony

In our symfony2 app we offer authentication against internal (FOS) user database and LDAP. We would like to have some specific behaviour in case LDAP has been used for authentication. How is it possible to find out in the controller which mechanism has been used by the user?

The relevant security config file looks as follows:

```
    firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
            default_target_path: /
            always_use_default_target_path: false
            use_referer: true
        form_login_ldap:
            service: app.ldap
            dn_string: %ldap_dn_string%
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
            always_use_default_target_path: false
        logout:
            path: fos_user_security_logout
            target: /
            invalidate_session: true
        anonymous:    true
```

Answer (score 0):

If u do something like this

```
    form_login:
        provider: fos_userbundle
        csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager
        login_path: /login
        check_path: /login_check
        default_target_path: // route name of your common controller
        always_use_default_target_path: true
        use_referer: true
    form_login_ldap:
        service: app.ldap
        dn_string: %ldap_dn_string%
        login_path: /login
        check_path: /login_check
        default_target_path: // route name of your ldap controller
        always_use_default_target_path: true
```

you can know what form the user have used because you do that you want in deferent controllers